# Switching on android GPS location

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm baffled. I have 2 apps which I'm working on, both doing similar things, grabbing and parsing GPS data. One version seems to automatically switch on the GPS service, looks for a signal and determines position. Android Studio is happy with this. The second version, where I have used the same code, Android Studio raises an error will not compile and suggests asking the user to switch on the GPS. I can't understand what I've done different. For version 2, I'd prefer it to function like version 1.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Without code this question is unanswerable.  But I guarantee you that not having GPS on will not cause Android Studio to not compile, so something about your question is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a lint error I've never heard about.